# Prolog make rule execute once

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to make a prolog rule execute only once?
For example, I have this algorithm that copies the first and every nth element from List1 to List2:

```
ith_element(N, List1, List2) :-
    X is N - 1,
    length(A,X),
    append(A, [Head | Tail], List1),
      everyNth(N, Tail, Rest ->
      List2 = [Head | Rest]
    ; List2 = [Head | []]
    ).
```

Can I somehow make a rule that would copy the first element from List1 only once? I'm just learning Prolog and I can't find anything similar anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should keep the first element 'patching' out of the loop:

```
firstAndEveryNth(N, [F|List1], [F|List2]) :-
    everyNth(N, [F|List1], List2).
```

*edit* you can encode further info in arguments, but of course it's kind of a 'weird hack'

```
everyNth(N, [F|List1], [F|List2]) :-
    integer(N), % or N \= every(_), 
    everyNth(every(N), [F|List1], List2).

everyNth(every(N), List1, List2) :-
    X is N - 1,
    length(A, X),
    (  append(A, [Head | Tail], List1),
       everyNth(every(N), Tail, Rest)
    -> List2 = [Head | Rest]
    ;  List2 = []
    ).
```

*edit* swapping the rules, should work as well, without needing to check the 'type' of N

```
everyNth(every(N), List1, List2) :-
    !,  % needed to avoid an error on backtracking
    X is N - 1,
    length(A, X),
    (  append(A, [Head | Tail], List1),
       everyNth(every(N), Tail, Rest)
    -> List2 = [Head | Rest]
    ;  List2 = []
    ).

everyNth(N, [F|List1], [F|List2]) :-
    everyNth(every(N), [F|List1], List2).
```

Comment: That's how I would do it, but the goal is to not use auxiliary predicates. This problem is driving me up the wall.

Comment: Can't use any support predicates, only append and length.

Comment: then swap the rules. `everyNth(every(N), List1, List2) :-` will fire only when needed